# How to search in a file the best, easiest way?

Tags: c++, search, file-io

Can somebody tell me if this is a good way to search an account by an id, and to output all data about him? If not, which is the best way?

I have this:

```
void account::showacc() {
  ifstream inFile;
  inFile.open("account.dat",ios::binary|ios::in|ios::app);
  int accnum1,n;
  cout<<"Enter account num: ";
  cin>>accnum1;
  n=test();

  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    inFile.read((char*)&acc,sizeof(acc));
    if(accnum==accnum1)
    {
      cout<<"account number is: "<<accnum<<endl;
      cout<<"The possesor's name is :"<<name;

    }
  }
  inFile.close();
}
```

And the `test()` is:

```
int account::test()
{
  ifstream inFile;
  inFile.open("account.dat",ios::binary|ios::in|ios::app);
  inFile.seekg(0,ios::end);
  int n;
  n=inFile.tellg()/sizeof(acc);
  inFile.close();
  return n;
}
```

Comment: This would possibly have been better at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, a site designed specifically for this type of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this would work, but it's going to be slow ... depending on how big your file is, and how long your program runs (i.e., if it's a persistent program running in the background or a service of some type), it would be a much better idea to memory-map the file, and/or read the entire file into a `std::stringstream`, and then scan the stored file in memory.  Again, this will all depend on how big your file is, and how persistent the reading program is.  If it's a huge file, and your program is only run once and then quit, then yes, your current method is okay.

Answer (score 1):

You could make it much more efficient by changing the for loop. As it is, it looks like you go through the entire file, even if you find the account number. Assuming that there are no duplicate numbers, you should set it up to terminate if it finds the the number.

Comment: Great. Other than that, this method should work for you. But how is your file organized? Other search methods would work better if it isn't random.

Comment: i have a binary file (account.dat) in wich i store all info about accounts (bank accounts). i have no idea how it's organized). What are those search methods?

Comment: Nevermind, sorry. I don't know what I'm talking about and got confused. There probably are, I'd look at Jason's post below.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your use case, you might be better off using a database engine such as [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/) and let it take care of the searching for you. Sqlite exists as a C++ library that you can use in your program.